# Como aplicar formato de Data/Hora em uma coluna de um DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Tenho um componente Datatable e gostaria de formatar o Target[4] com uma formato de data/hora (ex: 12/09/2019 14:23:00), pois está vindo do banco com uma formato muito grande. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var table = $("#dtSistemaBackupIndex").DataTable({
"processing": false, // for show progress bar
"serverSide": true, // for process server side
"filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
"orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
"ordering": true, //Ativar/Desativar Ordenação de colunas 
"order": [[1, "asc"]], //Ordenar da segunda coluna em diante para não atrapalhar a coluna [0] da seleção
"ajax": {
    "url": '/sistema-backup-gerenciar/getSistemaBackup',
    "type": "POST",
    "datatype": "json"
},
"columnDefs": [
    //Estilos Das Colunas
    { className: "align-center", "targets": [0] },
    { className: "align-left", "targets": [1] },
    { className: "align-left", "targets": [2] },
    { className: "align-left", "targets": [3] },
    { className: "align-left", "targets": [4] },
    { className: "align-center", "targets": [5] },

    //Largura das Colunas
    { width: 10, targets: 0 },
    { width: 50, targets: 1 },
    { width: 250, targets: 2 },
    { width: 200, targets: 3 },
    { width: 50, targets: 4 },
    { width: 50, targets: 5 },
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
],        

"columns": [
    {
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<td><span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input class="selectable-item" type="checkbox" id="' + full.id + '"><label></label></span></td>';
        }
    },
    { "data": "backupFormaDescricao", "name": "BackupFormaDescricao", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "nomeArquivo", "name": "NomeArquivo", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "backupArquivoSituacao", "name": "BackupArquivoSituacao", "autoWidth": true },
    { "data": "dataHoraInclusao", "name": "DataHoraInclusao", "autoWidth": true },
    {
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<div class="btn-group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown" role="group"><a id="btnEditar" data-modal="" href="/sistema-backup/backup-detalhes/' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Visualizar Detalhes"><i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a id="btnExcluir" data-modal="" href="/sistema-backup-gerenciar/remover-backup/' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Excluir"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a id="btnDownloadBackup" data-id="' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title = "Download" ><i class="icon wb-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a ><a id="btnRestoreBackup" data-id="' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title = "Restaurar"><i class="icon wb-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>';
        }
    }

],
"language": {
    "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ".",
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
    "sProcessing": startLoadDataTable(),
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
    "searchPlaceholder": "Digite algo...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sNext": "Próximo",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior",
        "sFirst": "Primeiro",
        "sLast": "Último"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode converter para o formato `dd/mm/aaa hh:mm:ss` usando `.toLocaleString()` dentro de uma função `render` no target 4.

É só trocar a linha:

```
{ className: "align-left", "targets": [4] },
```

Por:

```
{ className: "align-left", "targets": 4, render: function(data){
      return new Date(data).toLocaleString();
   }
},
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sam!!